# Find length (miles or km) of polyline using Here maps javascript

Tags: here-api

I have many polylines coming from a KmlGroup. I would like to be able to display the length of each polyline. It looks like h.Map.Polyline.getBounds() does not have an option for returning the length of the line. Does anyone have a suggestion on how I could get this data?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly get the length of a polyline. Length of a polyline is nothing but distance between two coordinates. This you can achieve by using the Routing API and finding the distance.

Retrieve the lat,lng points of your polyline using getGoemetry().getLatLngAltArray method (example: map.getObjects()[0].getGeometry().getLatLngAltArray()). Pass this to the routing api waypoint parameter and get the distance. Hope this helps!

```
https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?waypoint0=52.5160%2C13.3779&waypoint1=52.5206%2C13.3862&mode=fastest%3Bcar%3Btraffic%3Aenabled&app_id=devportal-demo-20180625&app_code=9v2BkviRwi9Ot26kp2IysQ&departure=now
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it manually. Get the geometry from the line ([H.map.Polyline#getGeometry](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-map-polyline.html#h-map-polyline__getgeometry)), then walk over points and calculate the distance between each. Something along the lines of:

```js
function getPolylineLength(polyline) {
  const geometry = polyline.getGeometry();
  let distance = 0;
  let last = geometry.extractPoint(0);
  for (let i=1; i < geometry.getPointCount(); i++) {
    const point = geometry.extractPoint(i);
    distance += last.distance(point);
    last = point;
  }
  if (polyline.isClosed()) {
    distance += last.distance(geometry.extractPoint(0));
  }
  
  // distance in meters
  return distance;
}
```